# How to determine transfer function to control heater with PID method?

Tags: pid-controller

I want to make a PID controller for heater, but I confused how to determine the transfer function.
i use 60 watt solder element as heater, thermocouple max6675 as temperature sensor. please help me to find transfer function

Answer (score -1):

Start with the element off and cold. Turn on full power and record the 6675 outputs over time. You'll see temperature rise quickly, then more and more slowly, and finally reach a final value. The final value gives you the overall gain, and fitting the history to an exponential will give you the primary time constant.

Comment: and the transfer function? i'm still not understand.

Comment: Assume the transfer function is a 1-pole low-pass filter. Then the step response is used to determine the transfer function.